# Magento: How do I properly install a custom attribute into the DB tables?

Tags: magento

I've been doing some modifications my magento install to make it fit my needs but I'm come accross quite a few walls. This are some of the things I've done just incase it's needed as a reference for my upcoming question.

[Magento: Add New Field to Credit Card Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854903/magento-add-new-field-to-credit-card-form)

[Magento: How to display customer's phone number on customer information field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849449/magento-how-to-display-customers-phone-number-on-customer-information-field)

[Magento: How to Add Order / Payment information to Admin-BackEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939139/magento-how-to-add-order-payment-information-to-admin-backend)

[Magento: How to save data to order_payment and quote_payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957429/magento-how-to-save-data-to-order-payment-and-quote-payment)

So I've followed a few tutorials about adding a custom attribute but I'm puzzled as of how to run a script to add the attributes to the correct tables.

Here's why.

I noticed that the "telephone" field that already comese with magento, appears on several tables.

eav_attributes (4 instances) then the attribute_id for the telephone field also appears on other tables, all 4 instances of it. Now I have added a Mobile telephone number field as seen on my previous questions but I don't know how to make it appear on all of those tables with the necessary values.

I'm a bit limited on resources right now to provide more detailed information, but if someone can understand what I'm trying to explain, please assist me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

- Use a setup script executed by the entity module's setup resource class.

## Why?

While there are classes and tables which are common to all EAV attributes and entities (e.g. `eav_attribute` table and `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`), each EAV entity *may* have an additional attribute info table. The generic setup resource class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` has a `_prepareValues()` method which sets defaults for all of the generic attribute metadata (i.e. the columns in the `eav_attribute` table). In the case of `Mage_Customer`, there is the `customer_eav_attribute` table among others. The `Mage_Customer` setup resource class `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` overrides this method, calling the parent method and adding *more* metadata defaults which are stored in the `customer_eav_attribute` table.

So, while a setup resource file can execute in any context (setup class instance), if it is modifying some other module's EAV configuration, it needs to do so with the correct class.

```
<?php

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/setup','customer_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'customer',
    'new_attribute_code',
    array('label'=>'Label','type' => 'text')
)

$installer->endSetup();
```

Depending on the need to add to customer / customer address forms, there is further work to be done. References for this type of work can be found in `Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will work on a setup script for the necessary attributes and give it a try and hope it works. Manually adding/removing values from the DB is not exactly something I wanted to do but wasn't quite sure what was the best approach.